# c++ vector rotation all combinations

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to find all possible vector rotation combinations for a given vector. My code finds a specific element sequentially in a vector and then rotates around that, but this logic fails when two same elements are occurring consecutively like in {1,1,2}
Below is the code snippet, can someone help me to circumvent this issue, preferably by lets say an if else loop inside my for loop.

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;
vector<vector<int> > allrot(const vector<int>& a);

int main()
{
      int myints[] = { 1, 1, 2 };
      std::vector<int> a (myints, myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int));
      std::vector<vector<int> > b;
      b = allrot(a);
}

vector<vector<int> > allrot(const vector<int>& a) {
        std::vector<vector<int> > b;
        for(int i = 1; i <= a.size(); i++) {
                //int k;
                //if (a[i] == a[i+1])
                    //k = a [i+1];
                //else
                    //k = a[i];

                auto pivot = std::find(a.begin(), a.end(), a[i]);
                std::vector<int> dest(a.size());
                std::rotate_copy(a.begin(), pivot, a.end(), dest.begin());
                for (const auto &i : dest) {
                    std::cout << i << ' ';
                }
                std::cout << '\n';
                b.push_back(dest);
        }
        return b;
}
```

Apologies if the question looks naive, i'm new to c++.

Comment: If this in not a homework and you need it for a program, consider [std::next_permutation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

Comment: In c++, the index in arrays (and std::vector) is 0-based. Apropos `for(int i = 1; i <= a.size(); i++)' and next 'auto pivot = std::find(a.begin(), a.end(), **a[i]**);`

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi, I feel like all permutations and all rotations are very diffrent. (i.e. there are `n` rotations but `n!` permutations).

Comment: Why do you use `find` to search for `a[i]`, when you know full well that, by definition, it is located at index `i`? For that matter, why do you loop over indexes, rather than iterators? Why not `for (auto pivot = a.begin(); pivot != a.end(); ++pivot) {...}` and then skip your `find()` call?

Comment: @TimothyMurphy you are right they are a different thing, theoretically right on the number of permutations, practically wrong if you only consider lexicographically distinct permutations. Anyway, 'tis academic, as I failed to note the requirement of 'rotations'.

Comment: 'All rotations' or 'all *distinct* rotations'? If the former, then you don't need to worry about searching elements equal with a given value.

Comment: what does "rotation combinations" mean?  It might help to give example input and output.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code has a potential segmentation fault:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= a.size(); i++)
```

As the `std::vector` index is 0-based, `i = a.size()` is out of bounds.

For the actual question: Notice that if you want only distinct rotations, you only need to rotate initial vector up to the point when it repeat itself - that would be its period, and from that point there would be no new distinct rotations.

This period could be anything from 1 to `a.size()`, and it always exists so reaching it should be your halting condition.

The possible algorithm would be

- make a temporary copy `b` of initial vector `a`
- push `b` into resulting vector
- rotate `b` by 1
- compare `b` to `a`. If equal, return your resulting vector, otherwise go back to step 2

Vector comparison (last step) is somewhat computationally heavy and can be optimized, e.g. period will always be a divisor of `a.size()` so you can skip some steps based on that.

Also you may want to switch to more rotation-friendly data structure, such as `std::list` or `std::deque`, at least for the object that handles actual rotations.

Comment: " e.g. period will always be a divisor of `a.size()` so you can skip some steps based on that." +Brilliant

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies with the line `auto pivot = std::find(a.begin(), a.end(), a[i]);` This will find the first instance that the value at `a[i]` occurs.

Instead consider the following implementation.

```
vector<vector<int>> all_rot(const vector<int>& a){
  vector<vector<int>> b;
  for (auto it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it){
    vector<int> dest(a.size());
    dest = std::rotate_copy(a.begin(), it, a.end(), dest.begin());
    if (b.size() != 0 && dest == b[0]){ return b; } // checks to see if you have repetition in cycles.
    b.push_back(dest);
    for (const auto item& : dest){
      std::cout << item << " ";
    }
    std::cout << endl;
  }
  return b;
}
```

Since you know that the `pivot` (I called it `it` above) is at the `ith` location we don't need to find it. Although, since we only need iterators, I just iterated over each element in the input and rotated based on that element.

One other edge case to consider is when every element is the same. If all elements of the vector is the same there is exactly 1 distinct rotation.

Comment: If the requirement is "all *distinct* rotations", your algo fails to be minimal: consider {0,1,0,1,0,1} - you'll be generating 6 when only 2 are distinct.

Comment: That's true. I'll fix it.